# Vaciar un array en javascript despues de guardar su valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un array de Objetos en javascript

```
var todosTrabajosAux = [] ;
todosTrabajosAux.push(tareasTrabajadores); 
misTareas.push({
        "idEmpresa": idEmpresa,
         "todosTrabajos" : todosTrabajosAux
    });
```

donde

> tareasTrabajadores

es un array a su vez.
El problema que tengo es que en otro lugar de mi código, después de hacer

```
misTareas.push({
    "idEmpresa": idEmpresa,
     "todosTrabajos" : todosTrabajosAux
});
```

hago

```
tareasTrabajadores.length = 0;
```

y el array

> todosTrabajosAux

también se vacía, se queda en 0.
Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando creas un objeto, éste no se duplica al asignarlo a un identificador nuevo o al pasarlo como parámetro, es siempre el mismo objeto con varios punteros:

```js
//creo un objeto
let objeto1 = {
  atributo: 'Hola mundo'
}


let objeto2 = objeto1;
//tengo objeto1 y objeto2 apuntando a la misma instancia

//demostración: valor del atributo en objeto2
console.log(objeto2.atributo)

//modifico objeto1
objeto1.atributo = 'Otro texto';

//comprobamos de nuevo objeto2
console.log(objeto2.atributo)
```

Por tanto, en lugar de vaciar el array, simplemente crea uno nuevo, vacío:

```
tareasTrabajadores = []; // generamos otro array, una nueva instancia
```

Comment: Gracias !!!! muchas gracias!! llevaba dos horas volviéndome loco